# Añadir un texto HTMl a un array INCLUYENDO el último elemento

Tags: javascript, javascript-objeto

Tengo un array multidimensional creado y quiero añadir usando un bucle for in a cada elemento del subarray una etiqueta Html para cuando se recorra el bucle me salga por pantalla el elemento del array con su etiqueta HTML incluida.

Los 2 problemas que encuentro son:

- No soy capaz de que el html aparezca al final de cada elemento del array.
- No soy capaz de "vincularlo" para que en la funcion de borrar luego, elimine el registro.

  ```js
      var total_coches = [];


      let coche1= new coche("Bmw", "Serie3");
          let piezas1 = ["Llantas", "Asientos de cuero"];
          coche1.piezas= piezas1;
          total_coches[0] = coche1;

      let coche2= new coche("Mercedes","300");
          let piezas2 = ["Airbag", "Faros"];
          coche2.piezas= piezas2;
          total_coches[1] = coche2;

      let coche3= new coche("Jaguar","XJS");
          let piezas3 = ["Techo Solar", "Faros"];
          coche3.piezas= piezas3;
          total_coches[2] = coche3;

  function mostrarCoches(){
          let p= document.getElementById("listadoCoches");
          p.innerHTML=""; 
          for (let key in total_coches) {
      
                  let marca= total_coches[key].marca;
                  let modelo= total_coches[key].modelo;
                  let piezas= total_coches[key].piezas;
                  let pos = total_series.indexOf(total_coches[key]);
                  let borrarBut = '<button onclick="deleteCoche()"> Borrar Pieza</button>';     
              p.innerHTML += `<div>Marca: `+ marca +
              `-- Modelo: `+ modelo +
              `-- Accesorios incluidos: `+ piezas.concat(borrarBut) +
             ` </div><button id="`+ pos +
              `"onclick="deleteCoche()"> Borrar Coche</button><br>`;
              
          
          }
          
        }
  ```

Comment: puedes poner lo que contiene la variable `total_coches`

Comment: Lo añado en el principal que se ve mejor

Comment: probe tu codigo , sumandole la funcion constructora y va bien(le saque la variable de pos porque no habia referencia de total_series) , no se te renderiza el html directamente ?

Comment: Facu, No soy capaz de que el html aparezca al final de cada elemento del array. Si solo me añade el botón al ultimo de los 2 elementos del array, la idea es que cada elemento pueda ser eliminado de manera individual, Gracias por la ayuda de antemano

Answer (score 0):

Solventado.

Cree un bucle for dentro del for in llamando al array y usando el indexOf para sacar la posicion y concatenando con Strings en vez de usar el metodo concat

Gracias a tod@s.